# what is the difference between logic,reg and wire in system verilog?? explaination with an example would be helpful

Tags: system-verilog

explanation with an example would be helpful.i tried:- input logic [9:0] data1 as the input of the counter and loaded this value into the count1 (logic [9:0] count;)
and then assigned count1<=data1; at the time when load was 1. but it shows some error.

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely no difference between `reg` and `logic` in SystemVerilog except for the way they are spelled - they are keyword synonyms. `logic` is meant to replace `reg` because `reg` was originally intended to be short for reg*ister*. Also note that `logic` is a data type for a signal, whereas wire is a signal type. Another signal type is a variable.

See [this post](https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2013/05/03/wire-vs-reg/) for a more complete explanation.

Comment: It is totally wrong to say that there is absolutely NO difference between the two. There are many limitations a logic pose. The major difference is that logic will not allow multiple drivers to drive a single variable at the same time and the simulator throws an error. This feature was introduced in SV to ensure that no Write-Write Race takes place.

Comment: @VidushiBajpai I stand by my answer. Show me a piece of code that works using one type and not with the other

Comment: @dave_59 There is a lexical restriction on the reg keyword, see §6.7.1 LRM 1800-2017. A net type keyword directly followed by reg keyword is not allowed. E.g. wire reg is not allowed, tri reg is not allowed, ...